# Xamarin.Forms - Get notified if the location authorization state has been changed

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, cllocationmanager

I tried to implement a solution, in `Xamarin.Forms` for iOS, which notified me if the user changed the authorization state for the location (see the code below). Because the first time if the app starts is the authorization denied or not determined (I don't know this exactly).
But it seems not to work, the event will be triggered only before the user tab on allow or denied.

Maybe someone else have an better idea or an other solution for this. I have oriented myself on [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreLocation.CLLocationManager/).

My class with the map in it (the view or what ever):

```
public partial class MapsView : ContentPage
{
    ILocation locService;

    public MapsView()
    {
        ...
        locService = DependencyService.Get<ILocation>();
        // Create method to listen for the event.
        locService.AuthorizationChanged += MapsView_AuthorizationChanged;
    }

    private void MapsView_AuthorizationChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Do stuff with the location.
    }
}
```

My Interface for the dependency injection:

```
public delegate void AuthorizationChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
public interface ILocation
{
    event AuthorizationChangedEventHandler AuthorizationChanged;

    void OnAuthorizationChanged(EventArgs e);
}
```

And the iOS specific code:

```
public class Location : ILocation    
{
    public Location()
    {
        var manager = new CLLocationManager();

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();

        manager.AuthorizationChanged += (sender, args) => {
            // Trigger event.
            OnAuthorizationChanged(new EventArgs());
        };
    }

    public event AuthorizationChangedEventHandler AuthorizationChanged;

    public void OnAuthorizationChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthorizationChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know there is a [plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) available for this? :)

Comment: Now. :) I will try this tomorrow thank you!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis There is no event or functionality for this in it.